# PostgreSQL: How can I check if table was created `WITH OIDS`?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to upgrade PostgreSQL database to new version of this database which doesn't support OIDS. Some of the tables was created with `WITH OIDS`. I think it was by `default_with_oids` setting. Is there information if table was created `WITH OIDS` in system schema tables `information_schema.*` or in system catalog tables `pg_*` or in other place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is stored in [pg_class.relhasoids](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-class.html)

So to get all tables created with OIDs you can use something like:

```
select relnamespace::regnamespace::text as table_schema,
       relname as table_name
from pg_class
where relhasoids
  and relnamespace <> 'pg_catalog'::regnamespace;
```